# Simulate Inspect Element tool with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-inspector

I am attempting to make an inspect element-like tool using JS. In most browser's inspect tools you are able to hover over elements on the page and click them to show where they are in the website's code. The only way I can think of simulating this is to add event listeners to every element on the page. I feel that this is bad for a lot of reasons. Is there any other way I can do this? If not, would adding event listeners to every element on the page be a good idea?

Comment: You can use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) which allows you to attach one event listener to a common parent, like `body` for example, and still be able to handle it for all descendants of that parent element.

Comment: I just had a problem with event propagation and I still didn't think of this. But if an element has a `stopPropagation` function attached to it would this method still work?

Comment: Well don't use it in this particular event handler.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/1jvdacrk/2/ It has dual mode (you can both highlight from the dom tree on the left and the page itself on the right). The code is a bit messy and it should be optimized and cleaned but the idea is there.

Comment: Note that back in the days, before browsers implement their own dev-tools, we were using a script called *firebug*. There was a lite version running directly in the page, you may want to check [their source code](https://github.com/firebug/firebug-lite) if you really want to make this kind of project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript's [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) method to get the Element on which the cursor is present, by using mouse events to get the coordinates of the cursor.

Here's a code example:

```
function highlighter() {


    function getElementOnCoordinates(x, y) {
        return document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
    }

    let currentElement;
    window.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {


        if (currentElement) {
            currentElement.classList.remove('bordered')
        }

        let [x, y] = [event.clientX, event.clientY]
        currentElement = getElementOnCoordinates(x, y);

        currentElement.classList.add('bordered')
    });
}
```

As you can see, I have used the mouseover event on the window to get the coordinates of the cursor, and then using those x & y values I get the Element present on that location. Then I add a CSS Class which gives that element an outline.

There is also a condition that checks if there is already an element and removes the styling from it in order to remove that outline when coordinates change.

Comment: Please ask if you have any queries and also share your feedback as this is the first time I have answered here. I am trying to build a chrome extension that needs this functionality and was figuring out how to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe this is the first time I'm hearing about this method.

Comment: Glad to help you @luekbaja ;)